# JmDNS 3.4.1, does it support IPv6?

Tags: eclipse, bonjour, jmdns, slp

Does JmDNS 3.4.1 support IPv6? when I register a service with an IPv4 I can see it on other machines, but if I use an interface with an IPv6 address, I don't :(

Also, I get

> No support for IPv6 in jSLP yet (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/328074), skipping interface...

does JmDNS use SLP?

Comment: I've used the JmDNS browser, every thing works fine with IPv6. But, in the same browser (i.e the code) if I use a JmDNS instance instead of JmmDNS, it works only with IPv4, and not IPv6.
I have noticed that the browser isn't stable if we use JmmDNS (the services and types of services are not always displayed) that's why I replaced with JmDNS and it works perfectly (with IPv4), the services are ALWAYS displayed and updated.

Comment: So, finally my question is why we don't always get the services displayd with JmmDNS? and why there are problems if we use IPv6 and JmDNS? 
Sorry if it is a trivial question..
I would really appreciate any help

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Associating a JmDNS instance to each interface did the trick